# Trouble with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

I have a virtual host on my local machine that I have htaccess turned on for.  The problem is if I have an htaccess file in there the page downloads instead of showing.  Here's my vhost.

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/test
   <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/test">
    AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ServerName local.test.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

Here's my htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I'm sure the problem is the htaccess.  If I rename it, the page loads fine.

Comment: index.php.  But I think the problem was that the AddHandler is wrong.  Don't particularly need it, so not a big deal.  I need to get that environment variable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, just figured it out.  It was this line.

```
 AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

I removed it and it's fine.  I still can't get the environment variable to print.

```
echo getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');
```

Thoughts on that?